# C++ Pipes / ReadFile lpNumberOfBytesRead / DLL

Tags: c++, pipe, inter-process-communicat

I seem to have a problem with creating a pipe between my c# app & c++ app.
my c++ app is a dll that gets injected into a certain program, and opens
a pipe to my c# app.

My problem? in ReadFile lpNumberOfBytesRead (cbRead) is always returns 0

Code:

```
hPipe1=CreateFile(lpszPipename1,    GENERIC_WRITE ,0,NULL,OPEN_EXISTING,FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED,NULL);
hPipe2=CreateFile(lpszPipename2,    GENERIC_READ ,0,NULL,OPEN_EXISTING,FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED,NULL);

BOOL fSuccess; 
char chBuf[100];
DWORD dwBytesToWrite = (DWORD)strlen(chBuf);
DWORD cbRead;
int i;


while(1){
fSuccess = ReadFile(hPipe2,chBuf,dwBytesToWrite,&cbRead, NULL); 
if(fSuccess)
{
    //4Stackoverflow: This works
    msg = "";
    for(i=0;i<cbRead;i++){
        //4Stackoverflow: This never gets called, because cbRead is always 0
        MessageBoxW(NULL, L"Sent", L"Hooked MBW", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
        msg += chBuf[i];
    }
```

Comment: And `dwBytesToWrite` is non-zero?

Comment: hmm, i never use c++ but in this case i have to use it. isn't dwBytesToWrite always 100 because of strlen(... ? Or does it change to the length of chBuf when i call ReadFile? hmm didn't check this. Could be the problem, only why would chBuf be empty, gonna post c# code

Comment: On msdn dwBytesToWrite: _In_ DWORD nNumberOfBytesToRead,
So it should always be 100 right? maybe i should hardcode it just in case instead of using strlen

Comment: Ow yeah it was strlen :o waaw. Wierd that it doesn't give an error on compiling

Comment: This isn't a cause of your current problem, but you shouldn't use CreateFile with `FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED` and then pass in `NULL` into the last `ReadFile` parameter.  It might work now, but you will probably end up with intermittent bugs where ReadFile appears to not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `strlen` function actually counts every byte in whatever pointer you pass it, until it finds a byte which is equal to zero. If there is a zero in the first byte of `chBuf` then `strlen` will return zero.

As you don't seem to initialize or read into `chBuf` the content will be random.

What you're want to use is the `sizeof` operator:

```
DWORD dwBytesToWrite = (DWORD)sizeof(chBuf);
```

The `sizeof` operator when used on an array, returns the size in bytes of that array. However, be careful when using it on any other pointer, or array passed as an argument to a function, as then it will be the size of the actual pointer and not what it points to.